# How to .On() an event after .Off() this in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, unbind

I'm creating a responsive navigation bar. But I have some problems with this Jquery. I want to disable hover event if width <=768, and enable it in Desktop.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function (e) {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w <= 768) {
        $('nav').css({ display: "none" })
        $('#last').off('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout');
    }
    if (w > 768) {
        $('nav').css({ display: "block" })
        $('#last').on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout', function() { });
    }
});
```

What 's wrong with this code? Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier pattern to follow is to simply set a flag when the screen size changes and check the state of that flag in the event handlers. Otherwise you will need to detach/reattach the same function repeatedly which isn't ideal. Try this:

```
var lowRes = false;

$(window).on('load resize', function (e) {
    lowRes = $(window).width() <= 768;
    $('nav').css({ display: lowRes ? "none" : 'block' })
}); 

$('#last').on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout', function() {
    if (lowRes) 
        return;

    // logic here...
});
```

Comment: @RorMcCrossan, Could you describe your code below **display: lowRes ? "none" : 'block'**

Comment: That's called a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It means that if `lowRes` equates to true, `display` will be set to `none`, else `block`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, I'd recommend you do this in CSS (depending on what your handler will do).

If you toggle the visibility of an element on hover, for example, then set this element to `display: none !important;` inside the appropriate media query in CSS. (i.e. the hover will still work the same, but the result will never appear for mobile/tablet devices).

**Reason**

You have a JS event on window resize, and you're not even throttling it. Which means you will be taxing the browser, unnecessarily. It's not a strenuous task, but if it's one that can be tackled with CSS, you should consider doing so.